# Why questions like: "how to explain ... to a layman?" are tolerated?

Tags: discussion

One of the reasons to flag a question is when it seems to be *primarily opinion-based*.

In that case, why so many questions in the style: *How to explain ... for a layman?* are tolerated? They are very primarily opinion-based too, are not they?

*P.S.*

*I admit such questions are interesting and useful, but one can use sugar to answer and the other may choose salt to answer (if you understand what I mean)*

Comment: Sorry but in my English dictionary explaining something is not automatically related to opinions. Explaining Diffie-Hellman key exchange for a layman seems pretty factual to me. I consider your question opinion-based ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because user education is a large part of the job for many information security professionals.

Unlike [SO] or [SF], where it's (almost always) just about getting the job done, here we need to involve the user in that job. Indeed, sometimes the user IS the job.

"The user will always click for dancing pigs" ... and the user is always the weak link in any security chain.

And, well, users are not always very technical, or knowledgeable, or tolerable...  So explaining these complex InfoSec concepts to them, while required, can be quite tricky.

Comment: *and the user is always the weak link in any security chain.* Personally, that is the most convincing argument. Thank you.